# After enable the manual proxy in mobile my internet is not working for jmeter mobile performance testing

Tags: jmeter

0

I have to record HTTP traffic on my mobile phone with JMeter to do so I added HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder to Test Plan and set the port inside recorder to 8888. I also added Recording Controller inside Thread Group then I clicked Start button inside HTTP Proxy Server to generate certificate, after that I used ipconfig in the cmd to get my computer's IP address.

On my mobile I install transferred JMeter certificate and modify Wi-Fi network by setting parameter Proxy settings to Manual and typing IP of the computer as a hostname and 8888 as proxy port.

According to the instructions on the Internet, this configuration should allow me to record traffic on the phone, but nothing like that happens. It seems to me that something may be wrong with the proxy settings, because after I manually configured proxy the phone is offline. Does anyone know what the cause could be and how to fix this problem?

I had a doubt if i change my wifi public to private its working or not??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your "mobile" operating system you will have to perform some extra steps

- for iOS you will need to [enable full trust for JMeter's certificate](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477)
- for Android you will need to amend your application [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) and allow JMeter's certificate to decode and intercept the requests like it's described in [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)

Also JMeter itself needs to be able to connect to the Internet so if you're behind a corporate proxy you will need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

Comment: Im using mI os on these jmeter support mi phone os??

Comment: send me your mail id it will very useful for me to complete this task.